# multi-master file replication

Tags: filesystems, replication

I have a load balancer and several servers behind it. I'm looking for a multi master file replication tool that would allow me to write on any of the machines and replicate the content on all the others, on an event-basis, in a very small timeframe (5 sec).

A single NFS volume mounted on all servers will not suffice, because it becomes a single point of failure.

I'm running CentOS on the servers, the load balancer has proprietary software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [DRDB](http://www.drbd.org/) with [OCFS2](http://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/) as my filesystem.. works great.

The mistake a lot of people make with drdb is they use a non-clustered filesystem. Oracle packages ocfs2 for redhat/centos for all the kernels for v5

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about block-level replication with [DRDB](http://www.drbd.org/)?